# convert stringified json to jsonArray using kotlin in android

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I'm trying to convert this string to jsonArray.

```
for (jsonIndex in 0..(jsonArray.length() - 1)) {
          Log.d("JSON", jsonArray.getJSONObject(jsonIndex).getString("translation").toString())
}
```

however, this turns out not to be an object but a string, I'm quite sure its because of the way the someString is. Is there a way i could either fix this string or how should i proceed further?

```
 val wordReview = "[\n  \"{\\n  \\\"assignUser\\\" : false,\\n  \\\"transliteration\\\" : \\\"wa\\\",\\n  \\\"lessonNumber\\\" : 1,\\n  \\\"seen\\\" : 5,\\n  \\\"arabicWord\\\" : \\\"وَ\\\",\\n  \\\"translation\\\" : \\\"and\\\",\\n  \\\"priority\\\" : 2\\n}\",\n  \"{\\n  \\\"assignUser\\\" : false,\\n  \\\"transliteration\\\" : \\\"Maryam\\\",\\n  \\\"lessonNumber\\\" : 1,\\n  \\\"seen\\\" : 4,\\n  \\\"arabicWord\\\" : \\\"مَرْيَمَ\\\",\\n  \\\"translation\\\" : \\\"Maryam\\\",\\n  \\\"priority\\\" : 3\\n}\",\n  \"{\\n  \\\"assignUser\\\" : false,\\n  \\\"transliteration\\\" : \\\"allati\\\",\\n  \\\"lessonNumber\\\" : 1,\\n  \\\"seen\\\" : 4,\\n  \\\"arabicWord\\\" : \\\"الَّتِي\\\",\\n  \\\"translation\\\" : \\\"the one who\\\",\\n  \\\"priority\\\" : 6\\n}\",\n  \"{\\n  \\\"assignUser\\\" : false,\\n  \\\"transliteration\\\" : \\\"min\\\",\\n  \\\"lessonNumber\\\" : 1,\\n  \\\"seen\\\" : 4,\\n  \\\"arabicWord\\\" : \\\"مِنْ\\\",\\n  \\\"translation\\\" : \\\"from\\\",\\n  \\\"priority\\\" : 3\\n}\",\n  \"{\\n  \\\"assignUser\\\" : false,\\n  \\\"transliteration\\\" : \\\"kaanat\\\",\\n  \\\"lessonNumber\\\" : 1,\\n  \\\"seen\\\" : 5,\\n  \\\"arabicWord\\\" : \\\"كَانَتْ\\\",\\n  \\\"translation\\\" : \\\"was\\\",\\n  \\\"priority\\\" : 2\\n}\",\n  \"{\\n  \\\"assignUser\\\" : false,\\n  \\\"transliteration\\\" : \\\"rabbuha\\\",\\n  \\\"lessonNumber\\\" : 1,\\n  \\\"seen\\\" : 3,\\n  \\\"arabicWord\\\" : \\\"رَبُّهَا\\\",\\n  \\\"translation\\\" : \\\"her Lord\\\",\\n  \\\"priority\\\" : 4\\n}\",\n  \"{\\n  \\\"assignUser\\\" : false,\\n  \\\"transliteration\\\" : \\\"'Imran\\\",\\n  \\\"lessonNumber\\\" : 1,\\n  \\\"seen\\\" : 4,\\n  \\\"arabicWord\\\" : \\\"عِمْرَان\\\\n\\\",\\n  \\\"translation\\\" : \\\"Imran\\\",\\n  \\\"priority\\\" : 3\\n}\"\n]"
```

or this

```
 [
"{\n  \"assignUser\" : false,\n  \"transliteration\" : \" mann\",\n  \"lessonNumber\" : 4,\n  \"seen\" : 2,\n  \"arabicWord\" : \"مَنْ\",\n  \"translation\" : \" who\",\n  \"priority\" : 10\n}",
            "{\n  \"assignUser\" : false,\n  \"transliteration\" : \"'inda\",\n  \"lessonNumber\" : 4,\n  \"seen\" : 2,\n  \"arabicWord\" : \"عِندَ\",\n  \"translation\" : \"near\\\/with\",\n  \"priority\" : 10\n}"
]
```

we're saving this to firebase and its encoding \ to it, now i need this format to be readable from gson again.

Comment: there is no `jsonArray`. how shall one know of the input, while only seeing messy output?

Comment: reformatted, although this is what in a string i'm receiving, i need to be formatted into a jsonarray and then its particular objects.
i can read the jsonArray but when it comes down to object, these are all strings only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to parse your broken JSON twice.
One time to get list of strings:

```
val listOfStrings = Gson().fromJson(wordReview, mutableListOf<String>().javaClass)
```

And the other to parse each string.
Either as a map:

```
val asMap = Gson().fromJson(listOfStrings[0], mutableMapOf<String, Any>().javaClass)
```

Or as an object:

```
data class MyObj(val assignUser: Boolean,
                 val transliteration: String,
                 val lessonNumber: Float,
                 val seen: Float,
                 val arabicWord: String,
                 val translation: String,
                 val priority: Float)

val asObject = Gson().fromJson(listOfStrings[1], MyObj::class.java)
```

To convert it back to string once modified you can use:

```
Gson().toJson(asObject)
```