# How to parse a JSON string into a JSONObject in Kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I recently started a project in Kotlin with Android Studio.

So, I have a problem with a JSON object. I get data from an BroadcastReceiver object, a String to be more specific, with the next format:

```
{"s1":1}
```

This, is a simple string. So I took in a function call toJson and I do this.

```
private fun toJson(data:String): JSONObject {
    
    var newData: String = data.replace("\"","")
    newData = newData.replace("{","")
    newData = newData.replace("}","")

    val newObject = newData.split(":")
    val name = newObject[0]
    val value = newObject[1]
    val rootObject = JSONObject()
    rootObject.put(name,value)

    return rootObject
}
```

Am I doing this the right way? How can I improve my code?

Comment: *Im doing this the right way?* no, this is not feasible for more complex data. You can probably create a JSONObject from a string directly. Try `JSONObject(data)`

Comment: You should check this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777441/convert-stringified-json-to-jsonarray-using-kotlin-in-android][1]

Comment: If one of the answers was helpful for you then I suggest you to mark it as accepted below the voting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In 2019 no-one is really parsing JSON manually. It's much easier to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library. It takes as an input your object and spits out JSON string and vice-versa.

Example:

```kotlin
data class MyClass(@SerializedName("s1") val s1: Int)

val myClass: MyClass = Gson().fromJson(data, MyClass::class.java)
val outputJson: String = Gson().toJson(myClass)
```

This way you're not working with JSON string directly but rather with Kotlin object which is type-safe and more convenient.
Look at the docs. It's pretty big and easy to understand

Here is some tutorials:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-kcvxYZrB4
- http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-introduction/
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/index.htm

**UPDATE**: If you really want to use JSONObject then use its constructor with a string parameter which parses your JSON string automatically.

```kotlin
val jsonObject = JSONObject(data)
```

Comment: in all honesty gson should be part of android by now

Comment: Or Moshi (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577623/moshi-vs-gson-in-android and https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/684flw/why_use_moshi_over_gson/dgx3gpm/ in particular)

Comment: its 2022 and i am still surprised we cant write JSON directly in Kotlin backed by some DSL features. (Just like we can create objects in JS by simply using `{}` )

Comment: For me it compiles and then fails on execution with ```java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.gson.Gson```

Comment: Gson is located inside `com.google.gson` package. The package in your exception message is different so I guess you just didn't set it up correctly. Please refer to the official documentation.

Answer (score 11):

Best way is using kotlinx.serialization. turn a Kotlin object into its JSON representation and back marking its class with the `@Serializable` annotation, and using the provided `encodeToString` and `decodeFromString<T>` extension functions on the Json object:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*
​
@Serializable
data class User(val name: String, val yearOfBirth: Int)
​
   // Serialization (Kotlin object to JSON string)
​
   val data = User("Louis", 1901)
   val string = Json.encodeToString(data)
   println(string) // {"name":"Louis","yearOfBirth":1901}
​
   // Deserialization (JSON string to Kotlin object)
​
   val obj = Json.decodeFromString<User>(string)
   println(obj) // User(name=Louis, yearOfBirth=1901)
```

Further examples: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/10/kotlinx-serialization-1-0-released/

Answer (score 5):

I am adding 3 templates here for Kotlin Developers, It will solve json converting & parsing problems.

```
//Json Array template
{
  "json_id": "12.4",
  "json_name": "name of the array",
  "json_image": "https://image_path",
  "json_description": "Description of the Json Array"
}
```

Kotlin Model class

```
data class JsonDataParser(
  @SerializedName("json_id") val id: Long, 
  @SerializedName("json_name") val name: String, 
  @SerializedName("json_image") val image: String,
  @SerializedName("json_description") val description: String
)
```

Converting to Json String from the Model Class

```
val gson = Gson()
val json = gson.toJson(jsonDataParser)
```

Parsing from Json file/Strong

```
val json = getJson()
val topic = gson.fromJson(json, JsonDataParser::class.java)
```